# Antlr4 does not detect integer from 1 to 8, lexer problem

Tags: c#, antlr4

there is a problem with antlr 4 c# where it cannot recognize integer tokens. It works for number 1 and 9 but not 1 to 9!!

I tried rebuilding the grammar but it doesn't work :(.

Here is my grammar:

```
grammar simplerlang;

// Parser

program   : statement+ ;
statement : let | print ;
let       : VAR '=' INT ;
print     : 'print' (INT | VAR) ;

// Lexer

VAR : [a-z]+ ;
INT : [0–9]+ ;
WS  : [ \n\t]+ -> skip;
```

And here is my c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Antlr4.Runtime;
using Antlr4.Runtime.Tree;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SuperSimpleTestLang
{
    class Program
    {

        static Dictionary<string, int> variableMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("> ");
                string _in = Console.ReadLine();
                AntlrInputStream input = new AntlrInputStream(_in);
                simplerlangLexer lexer = new simplerlangLexer(input);
                CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
                simplerlangParser parser = new simplerlangParser(tokens);

                IParseTree tree = parser.statement();
                ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
                walker.Walk(new simplerlangCustomListener(), tree);
            }
        }

        class simplerlangCustomListener : simplerlangBaseListener
        {
            public override void ExitPrint(simplerlangParser.PrintContext ctx)
            {
                if (ctx.INT() != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ctx.INT().GetText());
                }
                else if (ctx.VAR() != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(variableMap[ctx.VAR().GetText()]);
                }
            }

            public override void ExitLet(simplerlangParser.LetContext ctx)
            {
                variableMap.Add(ctx.VAR().GetText(),
                int.Parse(ctx.INT().GetText()));
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**input:** print 1

**output:**
line 1:6 token recognition error at: '1'
line 1:7 missing {VAR, INT} at ''

**input:** print 0
**output:** 0

**input:** print 9
**output:** 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
VAR : [a-z]+ ;
INT : [0–9]+ ;
```

If you look closely at these two lines, you'll notice that the dash between 0 and 9 is longer than the one between a and z. This means that this isn't a regular dash, but a Unicode emdash (or something similar).

So ANTLR doesn't recognize this as a range, but as a character class matching 0, 9 or an emdash.